# Wordpress: links not working on homepage but works on inner pages

Tags: wordpress

I have migrated this site http://www.bangladeshdeltaplan2100.org from one host server to another.

In homepage, only Contact link works properly. But other links, slider, search are not working.

But from any other inner pages all the links are working perfectly.

I have tried by changing the .htaccess file and nothing happens.

I feel bit confused about this. How can i resolve this problem?

**EDIT1:** footer is also not showing in homepage.

Comment: I'd suggest transferring the site again with the theme and plugin files as there is too many errors. Or ask a developer to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your given link, You need to add some css fix to your `.header_container` class as below:

```
.header_container{
    z-index: 99999; 
}
```

OR

```
.slider_content_box{
    margin-top:0;
}
```

This is because in home page your slider is overlapping your header. See the below image.

[image]

Comment: And what about the links that are not working except Contact on header?

Comment: if you hover on the left part of the 'contact' link, you will see that link not working because your overlap part in 990px wide. For clarity see the attached image in the updated answer.

Comment: I get what you said. Thanks. But still your solution of increasing z-index is not resolving this problem. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: another solution is set `.slider_content_box{margin-top:0;}` in your custom.css

Comment: Thanks. It works. But still slider images are not showing properly. I have also edited my problem. Can you say the solution of these problems?

Comment: As your question title say **Wordpress: links not working on homepage but works on inner pages**, I think is resolved. Please be clear before posting the question. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)